# Access json which has no key in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a column "**value**" with type postgres '**JSON**'.
Example data in the **value** column.

1. "displayname1"
2. {"middleName": "other"}
3. [{"primary": true, "type": "work", "value": "rusr@r.com"}, {"primary": true, "type": "work", "value": "iu@n.com"}]

I know i can access json with key-value pairs like this,

`.filter(Values.value['middleName'].astext=='other')`(values is model name)

the question is how do you access string value or array of objects.

i tried,

`.filter(Values.value.astext=='displayname1')`
it gives me `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Values.value has an attribute 'astext'`

and

`.filter(Values.value['type'].astext=='work')`-  here i am trying filter "type":"work" objects in the array. How do you do this. Is it possible to search in all objects with out specifying the index.

I am using postgres as backend Db.

Models -

```
class Values(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_values'
                    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    attribute = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('attributes.id'), primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(JSON)
```

```
class Attributes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

   user_attribute = db.relationship(Values, backref='attributes', primaryjoin=id == Values.attribute)
```

query that i am trying -

```
db.session.query(Values).join(Attributes, Values.attribute == Attributes.id).filter("what filters that i should be using for the cases mentioned above").all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the json object is a string, use json.loads to convert it into a dictionary then index it normally.

```
>>> import json
>>> s = """[{"primary": true, "type": "work", "value": "rusr@r.com"}, {"primary": true, "type": "work", "value": "iu@n.com"}]"""
>>> my_dict = json.loads(s)
>>> my_dict[0]['type']
'work'
```

Then you can search for any lines where type == work using the following list comprehension.

```
>>> search = [i for i in my_dict if i['type'] == 'work']
>>> search
[{'primary': True, 'type': 'work', 'value': 'rusr@r.com'}, {'primary': True, 'type': 'work', 'value': 'iu@n.com'}]
```

Here is an example of the same thing without using a list comprehension.

```
>>> search = list()
>>> for i in my_dict:
...     if i['type'] == 'work':
...             search.append(i)
...
>>> search
[{'primary': True, 'type': 'work', 'value': 'rusr@r.com'}, {'primary': True, 'type': 'work', 'value': 'iu@n.com'}]
```

Comment: This is correct, but how to do this in context of sqlalchemy is what i am looking at.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. Let me work on finding a solution that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I can not test the code, but you can try this.

```
l = .filter(User_Values.value)
s = [[x for x in i if x['type'].astext=='work'] for i in l if isinstance(i, list)]
```

I can do testing to provide a better answer if I can be provided with the code to create the table. Sorry in advance if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  i have provided the code  and the query in my last edit

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for answer, here is how its done

```
(cast(Values.value, db.String())=='"Employee"'))
```

The above is for string stored in JSONB column. Note the quotes used in that filter.

```
(Values.value.contains([{"type":"examplecom"}]))
```

This one is for searching array of JSON inside JSONB column